# How to run nest add in nx monorepo?

Tags: azure-functions, nestjs, command-line-interface, nrwl-nx, nrwl

I want to use **@nestjs/azure-func-http** in my nx monorepo, but I'm struggling with something simple.

How does one run `nest add @nestjs/azure-func-http` the NX way?

When I want to run `ng add @angular/pwa`, I can use this schematic (`npx nx g @angular/pwa:ng-add --project myangularproject`)... I cant seem to figure anything similar for nest.

From the docs I would expect to try something like this

```
me@mbp myproject % npx nx add @nestjs/azure-func-http --project=api

>  NX   Ran target add for project api (22ms)

✖    0/0 failed
✔    0/0 succeeded [0 read from cache]

View logs and run details at https://nx.app/runs/yK9Q9l3Sg6


>  NX   Cannot find configuration for task api:add

...
```

If I try something like this, I get...

```
me@mbp myproject % npx nest add @nestjs/azure-func-http --project=api 
npm ERR! could not determine executable to run

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/ryankirby/.npm/_logs/2022-11-28T11_36_49_549Z-debug-0.log
```

Edit: I ended up installing the @nestjs/cli and then ran

```
npx nest add @nestjs/azure-func-http --project=api
```

then manually went through removed and updated the files. It wasn't ideal but limped me forward.

Comment: you could try to use the nx console extension for your IDE instead of CLI. That should work correctly with the schematics

Comment: I am just curious where you ended up on this? I am trying to do the same thing, and there is no clearly documented way to do this. Ive got my nest.js api in my apps/myapp folder, but if I run the nest add with the --project=apps/myapp it creates the functions.json root of the app but still puts the main.azure.ts in the root of the mono repo in a new /src directory. Not sure where everthing is supposed to go.

Comment: @Brandon, it was a bear. I'm still hoping this question gets answered with something much easier and more easily repeatable. 

The short version, I ran the command on a vanilla nestjs app and made note of the file diffs. Then manually made each update to my NX project. It was a bunch of trial and error WRT the output of the build process being what Azure expected.